# Net Suite How to link two record types?

Tags: netsuite

I created a custom entity field 'countryZone' on customers, which links to a custom record type 'countryZone'. And I set the filter on customer.country == countryzone.country. I can link this two 'table' just fine, but the question is how to fill the value to this custom entity field 'countryZone' when the customer is created ? This field is always empty unless I manually edit the customer record and set the value.

Answer (score 1):

Either via WorkFlow or SuiteScript User Event script, create an "after submit" function that copies country to countryzone.country.

There is also a "Default Value" setting on the custom field. Set it to equal the value of the customer.country.

Comment: Hi Dave, is this possible to achieve this without SuiteFlow and SuiteScript ? I don't have them neither. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you have SuiteFlow? Just turn on the feature. Same for SuiteScript.